# How do I switch between two cameras (UnrealEngine 4/C++)?

Tags: c++, camera, unreal-engine4

I am working on a game prototype and I have this problem, how do i switch from a camera to another, like in GTA V for example from third person to first person.

I saw an answer to a question like this, but he was using blueprints and i work with code.

Comment: Please provide some sort of code sample to illustrate what you are trying to achieve. Also take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

PlayerController class has methods SetViewTarget and SetViewTargetWithBlend which do exactly this. I recommend the latter, cause it allows for smooth changing of cameras.